# How to extract folder name from mysql url and delete it with all content?

Tags: php, mysql, url, delete-file, unlink

How to get image folder -> subfolder name -> from MySQL URL:

```
images/5d049d4ac96e6/image.jpg
```

and delete it with all content. 
At the moment code delete `image.jpg` file only from image subdirectory but what I need is to delete also `subfolder /5d049d4ac96e6/`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT postImage FROM blog_posts_seo WHERE postID = :postID') ;
    $stmt->execute(array(':postID' => $_GET['delpost']));
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $delImage =  dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/'.$row['postImage'];
    unlink($delImage);
    //rmdir(?????);
    }
```

How to extract this part of mysql url: `/5d049d4ac96e6/`

Comment: `$row['postImage']` is this having `images/5d049d4ac96e6/image.jpg`

Comment: yes it is images/5d049d4ac96e6/image.jpg

Comment: you can use `$imageFolder = explode("/",$row['postImage']);` then check `print_r($imageFolder);` you will be having array `$imageFolder[1]=5d049d4ac96e6`

Comment: Array ( [0] => images [1] => 5d04ccb2b13e5 [2] => image.jpg )

Comment: print_r($imageFolder[1]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deleting the folder, delete all it's files and folders. Here is the function for that use it in `while` loop

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
  if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $objects = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
      if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
        if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") 
           rrmdir($dir."/".$object); 
        else unlink   ($dir."/".$object);
      }
    }
    reset($objects);
    rmdir($dir);
  }
}
```

In your while loop

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $dir = dirname($row['postImage']).'/';
    rrmdir($dir);
}
```

Comment: nothing happen, all files are unlink, folder is empty, should be deleted..

Comment: @Axīc nothing happen mean, is deleting files alone! or deleting nothing!? I tested in windows worked fine.

Comment: this part of code : unlink files: $delImage =  dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/'.$row['postImage'];
    unlink($delImage); is ok, works,  added code you shared but no luck, /5d049d4ac96e6/ still on place empty..

Comment: @Axic did u copied function `rrmdir($dir)`?

Comment: yes, I place it to function.php files as rest of functions, but no luck, already try $dir = 'image/subfolder/'; rrmdir($dir); to test, no luck also..